# Dynamic css not working in safari 11

Tags: css, angularjs, safari

I have a div that prints incrementing number.
This get incremented by `one way binding` variable

```
<div class="number">2</div>
```

CSS class:

```
.number {
 font-size: 5em;
 text-align: center;
 color: #3695D2;
 margin-top: -2.15em;
 }
```

This should display number 2, but 2 is being overlapped to previous number 1 and trimmed as well:

[image]

Its working fine in Chrome and Safari older version (< version11). The issue only exists on Safari version >11.

Comment: so you need to show the incrementation process, am pretty sure this static version will work

Comment: Yes static version is working fine, as value increments from 1 to 2 it don't appear correctly

Comment: si you need to share this code, as actually we have no change to see this behavior